# Определения языка браузера и последующий редирект - Согласно языку

Tags: php, java

Подскажите пожалуйста рабочий пример, для "Определения языка браузера и последующий редирект на русскоязычную версию сайта для русской версия браузера, английский язык во всех других случаях",

Например, в режиме инкогнито google chrome на MacOS всегда показывает английский язык, а Safari русский

Вот например при заходе на сайт [www.minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net) если у меня операционнка на русском языке во всех браузера, а также в инкогнито режимах перекидывает на русскоязычную версию сайта, как это реализовано?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через HTTP-заголовок Accept-Languag, этот вариант обсуждался на STACKOVERFLOW:
[Такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770616/7119024) вариант не подходит?

Comment: Google chrome - показывает как en; А,  Safari - показывает как ru; Хотя у меня оба браузера русско язычные и операционка MacOS - также на русском языке

Answer (score 0):

### в index.php в начало страницы вставил

```
<?php

preg_match('/^\w{2}/', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], $m);
switch (strtolower($m[0])) {
    case 'ru': header('Location: /ru/index.php'); break;
}
```

...
...
...

---

index.php - сайт на английском (по  умолчанию)
/ru/index.php - русская версия

Соответсвенно:

1. если у пользователя в браузере любая локаль(кроме русской) - index.php продолжает дальше програжаться
2. если у пользователя в браузере русская локаль index.php делает редирект на /ru/index.php